# Перенести часть битов между числами с помощью сдвигов

Tags: ассемблер

Из чисел `12345678h` и `90abcdefh` нужно получить `90ab56efh`.
В этом примере кода мы получаем `95678defh`, как получить `90ab56efh`?

```
format PE64 console
entry start
section '.data' data writable
bit_str1 dd 12345678h  ;90ab56ef
bit_str2 dd 90abcdefh
section '.text' code executable
start:
mov eax, [bit_str1] ;12345678
mov ebx, [bit_str2] ;90abcdef

rol ebx,4         ;0abcdef9
rol eax,16        ;56781234
shld ebx,eax,16   ;def95678
rol ebx,12        ;95678def
```

Comment: Не понятно зачем тут сдвиги. Если на Си записать, то `(bit_str1 & 0x0000FF00) | (bit_str2 & 0xFFFF00FF)`

Comment: @insolor 
Это лабораторная работа, нужно только сдвигами..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть два числа: `12345678` (в регистре `eax`) и `90abcdef` (в регистре `ebx`).

Нужно из первого вытащить `56` и воткнуть вместо `cd` во второе число.

1. Крутим первое число, так чтобы `56` оказалось слева (на край, чтобы потом при сдвиге двух чисел его переместить в другое число):

   ```
   rol eax, 16  ; должно получиться 56781234
   ```
2. Крутим второе число, так чтобы заменяемое `cd` оказалось тоже слева (опять же, на край, чтобы потом при сдвиге влево оно уехало из числа)

   ```
   rol ebx, 16  ; должно получиться cdef90ab
   ```
3. Дальше сдвигаем два числа вместе влево, чтобы `56` переехало из первого числа во второе, а `cd` из второго числа уехало (из-за переполнения разрядов числа)

   ```
   ; До операции: cdef90ab 56781234
   shld ebx,eax,8
   ; После операции: ef90ab56 78123400
   ```
4. Крутим второе (левое в предыдущей операции) число, так чтобы `56` оказалось на правильном месте:

   ```
   rol ebx, 8 ; должно получиться 90ab56ef
   ```